# Irregularly shaped forms

Tags: delphi

Many modern applications have irregularly shaped forms. What is the best way to do this in Delphi? Is it possible to do this without using any third party VCLs?

Comment: I don't believe the claim in your first sentence.

Comment: odd thing is, since Windows XP introduced themes, actually most windows have rounded corners (done with SetWindowRgn bij the themes service)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

yes is possible, you must use the [SetWindowRgn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145102%28VS.85%29.aspx) function to set the new window region to draw.

try this code

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  region:HRGN;
begin
  region := CreateRoundRectRgn(ClientRect.left, ClientRect.top, ClientRect.right, ClientRect.bottom, 15, 15);
  SetWindowRgn(Handle, region, true);
end;
```

[image]

check theses links for more info

- [Creating Shaped Forms](http://www.delphicorner.f9.co.uk/articles/forms13.htm) (using a bitmap image)
- [Is it possible to create forms with shapes other than the standard rectangular shape in Windows?](http://www.delphicorner.f9.co.uk/articles/forms4.htm) (using an poligon)

Comment: SetWindowRgn() is the old-school approach to shaping windows.  On Win2000 and later, UpdateLayeredWindow() and SetLayeredWindowAttributes() (which are wrapped by the TForm.TransparentColor... and TForm.AlphaBlend... properties) are are the preferred method now.

Answer (score 8):

You can use TForms's [TransparentColorValue](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Forms.TCustomForm.TransparentColorValue) property. In combination with BorderStyle=bsNone it will give you such shape.

Comment: If you mean Aero Glass, then yes.