# Shaping a Form around a png image delphi

Tags: delphi

I want to shape my form around my PNG image i loaded into it so there only will be an IPhone on desktop not a border.

Its like this right now:
[image]

Comment: Something like this http://stackoverflow.com/q/10532445/960757 ?

Comment: @TLama: no, I guess he wants his form to have a custom shape like an iphone...

Comment: Some clues here, [`Irregularly shaped forms`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3572342/576719).

Comment: @jpfollenius Thats right. But didn't found a solve for it yet

Comment: Try these articles [`Alpha Blended Splash Screen in Delphi - Part 1`](http://melander.dk/articles/alphasplash/1/), [`Alpha Blended Splash Screen in Delphi - Part 2`](http://melander.dk/articles/alphasplash2)

Comment: I haven't done anything with it, but I saw a demo of FM components, all of which have a Radius property.  If your objects all have circular corners, perhaps this property would help?  This is a rather crude approach, but thought I'd suggest it in case it was sufficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I really don't know what to make of your image. Either way you'll probably need to have a png that actually is transparent at the edges, I'll assume you do.

I have done this in VCL and FMX, in both approaches I placed a TImage on my form, set `MyImage.Align := alClient;` and `MyForm.BorderStyle := bsNone;`.

Using VCL, you can set the forms `MyForm.TransparentColor := true;`, `MyForm.Color := clFuchsia;` and `MyForm.TransparentColorValue := clFuchsia;` (or any color you would not normally use). In FMX you can set your `MyForm.Fill.Color := claNull;` and `MyForm.Transparency := true;`.